# How does Gboard implements floating keyboard, I need to do the same

Tags: android, user-interface, service, ime

I am creating a custom IME in android, and I want to implement a floating feature in it as google's Gboard does. Please give an idea how can we do that ?

Tried multiple open source IME codes but none of em has implemented a floating ime keyboard. I have no clue how can we do that.

Comment: Did you made any progress in that topic? I have the same question...